# roboearth: record object, could not get camera pose

Tags: ros, 3d-object-recognition, roboearth, ar-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to run the roboearth object recording package on electric turtlebot.

I started the turtlebot by running minimal bring up, run the kinect by ar_kinect_turtlebot.launch.

Now I run the ar_bounding_box and re_object_recorder, there's no point cloud in the GUI.

in the terminal running ar_bounding_box, I got log messages:

```
1.02 seconds needed for normal estimation
estimating normals
0.98 seconds needed for normal estimation
estimating normals
0.97 seconds needed for normal estimation
estimating normals
```

in the terminal running re_object_recorder, there's log messages:

```
[ INFO] [1330939288.173355473]: Received PointCloud
[ WARN] [1330939288.179008129]: could not get camera pose: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 1330939027.069164217 but the earliest data is at time 1330939278.591224731, when looking up transform from frame [/PATTERN_BASE] to frame [/camera_rgb_optical_frame]
[ INFO] [1330939295.673110834]: Received PointCloud
[ WARN] [1330939295.678817045]: could not get camera pose: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 1330939030.977755762 but the earliest data is at time 1330939285.791464750, when looking up transform from frame [/PATTERN_BASE] to frame [/camera_rgb_optical_frame]
[ INFO] [1330939303.667651668]: Received PointCloud
[ WARN] [1330939303.673169822]: could not get camera pose: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 1330939034.867899911 but the earliest data is at time 1330939294.192349816, when looking up transform from frame [/PATTERN_BASE] to frame [/camera_rgb_optical_frame]
```

And on the recorder_gui, there's no point cloud.

I try to change the distance and angle of the kinect, but couldn't get any useful point cloud.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thanks a lot!!

/gemini

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29096/roboearth:-record-object,-could-not-get-camera-pose/) by [Gemini Ma](https://answers.ros.org/users/1762/gemini-ma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2012-03-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gemini Ma](https://answers.ros.org/users/1762/gemini-ma/) on 2012-03-12**:
Thanks for the reply. I comment out the try-catch block and now get more useful point clouds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This seems to be a timing issue; ar_bounding box is running slow on your machine, thus some transformations are dropped. Some ideas:

- Try to increase the tf cache. In re_object_recorder/src/comthread.cpp, around line 59, change the ComThread constructor to e.g:

  ComThread::ComThread(QObject *parent) :
  QThread(parent), tf(ros::Duration(30.0))
- In re_object_recorder/src/comthread.cpp: Try to comment lines 115 - 129 out (this is a try-catch-block). This will disable storing the camera pose in the merged point cloud, which is not really necessary.

---

Originally posted by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) with karma: 916 on 2012-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0